# An issue with arguments for detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, pthreads, condition-variable

I am working on a school project (simulation of virtual memory), where we are supposed to use detached threads. There are also other limitations to what we can use but I will mention that later. The problem is that when I give the pthread_create function the last argument as (void*)something and the created thread is detached, the function called by pthread_create will recieve the argument, but since the thread is detached, the original arguments are deleted as soon as the function from where I called pthread_create finishes - that means the argument in the called function is no longer valid and therefore I get segmentation faults etc.. Here is a part of the code (cant post it whole, its very big):

```
bool CProcManager::NewProcess(void* processArg, void(*entryPoint)(CCPU*, void*), bool copyMem) {
uint32_t free_page;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t thread;

if (proc_cnt >= 63)
    return 0;

pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

if (!FindFreePage(free_page)) return 0;

free_page = (free_page << 12) | 7;
CProcManager ccpu(m_MemStart, free_page);
ThrArgs args(entryPoint, (void *) processArg, ccpu);

proc_cnt++;
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, StartWork, (void *) &args))
    return 0;

//pthread_mutex_lock(&start_mtx);
//pthread_cond_wait(&start_cond, &start_mtx);
//pthread_mutex_unlock(&start_mtx);

return 1;
}
```

Here you can see that this function gets a poitner to void and a pointer to function as parameters. pthread_creates tells the thread to call the "StartWork" function with argument "args", which is a structure containing a pointer to function, a pointer to void and an object of type CProcManager.

```
void* CProcManager::StartWork(void* arguments) {
//pthread_mutex_lock(&start_mtx);
ThrArgs *args = (ThrArgs*) arguments;
CProcManager ccpu = args->ccpu;

//pthread_cond_signal(&start_cond);
//pthread_mutex_unlock(&start_mtx);

args->entryPoint(&ccpu, args->processArg);

ccpu.RemovePage((ccpu.m_PageTableRoot >> 12) * PAGE_SIZE, false);

pthread_mutex_lock(&end_mtx);
proc_cnt--;
pthread_cond_signal(&end_cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&end_mtx);
return (NULL);
}
```

In this function, I finally call the function I had a pointer to. As you can guess, the arguments become invalid when the "NewProcess" function ends, so I tried to overcome this by adding a condition variable and somehow make a copy of the arguments I have (havent come to a solution yet) and then let the "NewProcess" function end. But there are certain limitations in this project. The function "NewProcess" is being called many times and the threads should run simultaneously (I tried signaling the condition variable after calling entryPoint and that worked), so I cant finish one thread and then do the next. The parameter "void* processArg" of the first function is originally a certain object type and this type cannot be accessed from the two functions above.

So can anyone please give me a suggestion how copy the arguments so I dont have a segmantation fault?

Comment: Well don't allocate the arguments on the stack and you're fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions.  The simplest is often just to allocate
the arguments dynamically: in `NewProcess`:

```
ThrArgs* args = new ThrArgs( entryPoint, processArg, ccpu );
bool results = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, StartWork, args ) == 0;
if (!results) {
    delete args;
}
```

(You could use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` here as
well.  In which case, *don't* call release on it unless
`pthread_create` succeeds!)

The alternative is to create a conditional variable over
a boolean, then wait on it before leaving the function, and copy
the parameters and then set the boolean in the new thread: in
`NewProcess`:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &theMutex );
freeToContinue = false;
bool results = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, StartWork, args ) == 0;
if ( results ) {
    while ( !freeToContinue ) {
        pthread_cond_wait( &theCond, &theMutex );
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &theMutex );
}
return results;
```

and in `StartWork` (the function you pass to `pthread_create`
must be `extern "C"`, and so cannot be a member):

```
void* StartWork( void* arguments )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &theMutex );
    ThrArgs args = *static_cast<ThrArgs*>( arguments );
    freeToContinue = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast( &theCond );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &theMutex );
    //  ...
}
```

(Obviously, I've left out a lot of error checking here.)

Either way: you may have to do something similar with regards to
the `processArg` argument, since its lifetime is determined by
that of the caller.

And you don't need all of the casts to `void*`.

Comment: Thanks, I feel quite stupid that I didnt realize I could use dynamically allocated variable. But at least I solved the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple and is one of object lifetimes and ownership.

You are passing the address of 'args' to the thread, but 'args' is created on the stack and goes out of scope soon after the thread has been started.

do it something like this:

```
// note: The ThrArgs constructor should take ownership of processArg
std::unique_ptr<ThrArgs> args (new ThrArgs(entryPoint, (void *) processArg, ccpu));
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, StartWork, (void *) args.get())) {
    args.release();
    // ownership of the pointer now belongs to the thread
    return 0;
}
```

then in the thread function:

```
void* CProcManager::StartWork(void* arguments) {
    std::unique_ptr<ThrArgs> args (reinterpret_cast<ThrArgs*>(arguments)); 

    // now use args as a pointer

    ....


    // the arguments will be deleted here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which, of course, leaks memory if the `pthread_create` fails.  When using smart pointers as you do, _always_ defer the `release` until you've verified that the C function has succeeded.

Comment: thats a fair point. I'll amend the code - there we go, fixed.

Comment: Yes.  Otherwise, it's the solution that I generally use (largely, however, because my "objects" are polymorphic, and can't be allocated on the stack anyway).  On the other hand, Boost threads uses the other solution I present in my answer, and that's what has been adopted in C++11.

Comment: Also, of course: the smart pointer doesn't help in the child thread if the thread terminates as a result of `pthread_exit` or `pthread_cancel`.  You can avoid `pthread_exit` easily by throwing an exception, and catching it and returning in the `StartWork` function.  For `pthread_cancel`, you'd have to register a clean-up routine, which would do something like `delete args.release();` (since you don't know whether the destructor of `args` will be called or not).

Comment: Thanks for this advice, however we are not allowed to use unique_ptr in this project. But I am glad that now I know how to use it :)

Comment: in that case you can do it without a unique_ptr. replace args.release() with delete args, where args is a pointer to a ThrArgs initialised with new.